# How to compare 3 json array in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here are the 3 JSON arrays from different responses.

I just want to print "Name" in case Book which has "size_id" be 1 then print "Name" and "Discripition"
and "Prize" who has category_id & Size_id match in Objective-C (on iOS).

```
 category
   [ {
        "Category_Id": "1",
        " Name": "Books",
          }
      {
        "Category_Id": "2",
        " Name": "Dummies",
      }

    product
    [
      {
        "Sub_Cat_Id": "3",
        "Category_Id": "1",
        "Size_id": "3",
        "Sub_Name": "java",
        "Description": "We are introducing new product.",
      },
      {
        "Sub_Cat_Id": "4",
        "Category_Id": "2",
        "Size_id": "3",
        "Sub_Name": "Android",
        "Description": "We are introducing new product.",
      },
      {
        "Sub_Cat_Id": "2",
        "Category_Id": "1",
        "Size_id": "1",
        "Sub_Name": "ios",
        "Description": "We are introducing new product.",
      },

    Prize
    [
      {
        "Size_Id": "1",
        "pirze": "600 "

      },
      {
        "Size_Id": "2",
        " pirze ": "300 "
      },
      {
        "Size_Id": "2",
        " pirze ": "800"
        }
```

Comment: Update your question with your attempted Objective-C code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest transforming this JSON into Foundation's `NSArray` via `NSJSONSerialization`'s `dataWithJSONObject:`. 
After that just use NSArray/NSDictionary filtering to retrieve your values

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create a class for your objects (category, product and prize), so you can create an objects for your readings and add them to a NSArray. Once you've got the objects in the same array you can apply a predicate to that array, in order to choose only the objects you want:

```
NSArray *objects = ...; // This is the array with your objects
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(prize.size_id == 1)"];
NSArray *array = [objects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:tiltPredicate]; // This is the array with the objects you want (size_id = 1)
```

Comment: I don't think predicates will work as the OPs JSON is misdefined to use string value for `size_id`.

Comment: Objects in the array must be a custom class with the required properties. So predicates can be applied. Let's say we create the Class `Whatever : NSObject` with properties category, product and prize (note you need to set the classes for these attributes too), so you can access to prize.size_id from your Whatever object.